# Bridging commands and concept: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: networking, ubuntu

I am using bridging as a technique to connect 2 virtual interfaces together in Ubuntu 12.04.
One of the interfaces is a mininet interface (www.mininet.org).
I am getting a lot of TCP retransmission packets, and the connectivity is extremely slow.
Trying to debug this issue.
I have tried to enable STP on the bridge, but it doesn't happen:

```
~$ brctl show
 bridge name    bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
 s1     0000.f643bed86249   no      s1-eth1
                                    s1-eth2
                                    s1-eth3
 s2     0000.caf874f68248   no      s2-eth1
 ~$ sudo brctl stp s2 on
 ~$ brctl show
 bridge name    bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
 s1     0000.f643bed86249   no      s1-eth1
                                    s1-eth2
                                    s1-eth3
 s2     0000.caf874f68248   no      s2-eth1
```

I am confused as to why this command does not work.
Also, auto-negotiation is off in these interfaces.

1. Does autonegotiation matter for virtual interfaces?
2. Should I manually set auto-negotiation to 'on' or set the duplex and speed of virtual interfaces?
3. Also,  ping and dns work perfectly fine. For http traffic, SYN, SYN-ACK and ACK is as expected, however, the GET/POST request gets retransmitted 5-6 time immediately after the first GET/POST.

This is a confusing thing for me now and any links/pointers/commands will be helpful.
Please direct me to the right forum if this is not a question for stackoverflow. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The STP is founded to solve the Lay2 looping and the broadcast storm that the Lay2 looping cause. It's nothing about the TCP retransmission.

Maybe you can check the DNS resolvf time out in your case, and turn on the web server debug log.